# How to extract line with specific word from text file

Tags: python

I need to extract all lines from a text file that contain the word true.

Example line in text file looks like this:

```
fficialprobl3mzombie@gmail.com | Full Name = Richard Shafer | Points Saved = false | Points = 0 | Member  = True 
fficialprobl3mzombie@gmail.com | Full Name = Richard Shafer | Points Saved = false | Points = 0 | Member  = False
```

I need to extract lines where it says "member true" and remove lines where it says "member = false", how can I achieve this? The code below doesn't work for some reason, nothing changes in the text file.

```
filepath = "cart.txt"
with open(filepath) as outfile:
    
    lines = outfile.read().splitlines()

    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
       
     for line in lines:
       if "True" in line:
         print(line, file=outfile)
         break
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have shown?

Comment: doesnt work , nothing changes in the text file

Comment: Did you mean `file=f`? `outfile` is the file you opened for reading.

Comment: @LeoBogod, in the future please be more specific than "doesn't work". We don't know what you expect your code to do. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Don't read the contents of the file while writing to it. Prefer create a new file then overwrite if needed:

```
import re
import shutil

with (open('cart.txt', 'r') as infile,
      open('cart_filtered.txt', 'w') as outfile):
    for row in infile:
        sre = re.search('Member\s*=\s*True', row)
        if sre:
            print(row.strip(), file=outfile)

# Move file if needed and you are sure to overwrite your original one
# shutil.move('cart_filtered.txt', 'cart.txt')
```

`cart_filtered.txt`:

```
fficialprobl3mzombie@gmail.com | Full Name = Richard Shafer | Points Saved = false | Points = 0 | Member  = True
```